# Save TreeView As TXT or XML

Tags: vb.net, treeview, save

Is there a way to save all the treeview items in visual basic as an TXT file (I Prefer TXT) or XML?

I also want to save it to my.settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive function e.g.

```
Public Class Form1
  Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Animal")
    TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Reptile")
    TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Dragon")
    TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Lizard")
    TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Mammal")
    TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(1).Nodes.Add("Cat")
    TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(1).Nodes.Add("Dog")
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Vegetable")
    TreeView1.Nodes(1).Nodes.Add("Fruit")
    TreeView1.Nodes(1).Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Apple")
    TreeView1.Nodes(1).Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Orange")
    TreeView1.Nodes(1).Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Pear")
    TreeView1.Nodes(1).Nodes.Add("Aubergine")
    TreeView1.Nodes(1).Nodes.Add("Carrot")
    TreeView1.Nodes(1).Nodes.Add("Cucumber")
    TreeView1.Nodes(1).Nodes.Add("Zucchini")
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Mineral")
    TreeView1.Nodes(2).Nodes.Add("Granite")
    TreeView1.Nodes(2).Nodes.Add("Quartz")
    TreeView1.Nodes(2).Nodes.Add("Topaz")

  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Multiline = True
    TextBox1.Height = 200
    TextBox1.Width = 200
    TextBox1.Text = WriteTreeView("", TreeView1.Nodes)


  End Sub


  Private Function WriteTreeView(ByVal parent As String, ByVal tnc As TreeNodeCollection) As String
    Dim strOutput As String = ""
    If tnc.Count = 0 Then
      strOutput = parent & vbCrLf 'leaf
    Else
      For i As Integer = 0 To tnc.Count - 1
        Dim strCurrent As String = ""
        If parent > "" Then strCurrent = parent & "."
        strCurrent &= tnc(i).Text
        strOutput &= WriteTreeView(strCurrent, tnc(i).Nodes)
      Next i
    End If
    Return strOutput
  End Function


End Class
```